# Can't use php_snmp.dll

Tags: php, snmp

Well the question is, i use windows 7 OS, denwer package. I've read almost all internet while searching for solving this problem, maybe you know how to fix it. When i try to execute simple function like

```
<?php
$value = snmpget(ip,community);
?>
```

or something like that it always says "call to undefined function  snmpget at line 2". I've downloaded php_snmp.dll, i've configured php.ini to make this thing work, i rebooted server, i've tried the instructions from http://php.net/manual/ru/snmp.installation.php, and there still was no signs of life. So i write here, maybe you're the chosen one to help me. If i missed post with the same problem please guide me, maybe it will help.